# Equivalent to autoconf's AC_CHECK_DECLS in CMake

Tags: c++, cmake

What is the equivalent to autoconf's AC_CHECK_DECLS in CMake?

I'm setting the following fixed definitions. I need to change it depend on the environment.

```
target_compile_definitions(myapp PRIVATE HAVE_ENDIAN_H=1 HAVE_DECL_BSWAP_16=1 HAVE_DECL_HTOLE16=1 HAVE_DECL_BE16TOH=1 HAVE_DECL_LE16TOH=1 HAVE_DECL_HTOBE32=1 HAVE_DECL_HTOLE32=1 HAVE_DECL_BE32TOH=1 HAVE_DECL_LE32TOH=1 HAVE_DECL_HTOBE64=1 HAVE_DECL_HTOLE64=1 HAVE_DECL_BE64TOH=1 HAVE_DECL_LE64TOH=1 HAVE_DECL_HTOBE16=1)
```

I'm looing into the same as autoconf AC_CHECK_DECLS feature in CMake.

**manual**

```
— Macro: AC_CHECK_DECLS (symbols, [action-if-found], [action-if-not-found], [includes = ‘AC_INCLUDES_DEFAULT’])
For each of the symbols (comma-separated list), define HAVE_DECL_symbol (in all capitals) to ‘1’ if symbol is declared, otherwise to ‘0’. If action-if-not-found is given, it is additional shell code to execute when one of the function declarations is needed, otherwise action-if-found is executed.
```

https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/manual/autoconf-2.65/html_node/Generic-Declarations.html

**example**

```
AC_CHECK_DECLS([le16toh, le32toh, le64toh, htole16, htole32, htole64, be16toh, be32toh, be64toh, htobe16, htobe32, htobe64],,,
        [#if HAVE_ENDIAN_H
                 #include <endian.h>
                 #elif HAVE_SYS_ENDIAN_H
                 #include <sys/endian.h>
                 #endif])
```

---

Update 1

@Tsyvarev gave me the answer. Thank you so much.

I changed the config as following. It works.

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE(endian.h HAVE_ENDIAN_H)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(htole16 "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOLE16)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(be16toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_BE16TOH)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(le16toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_LE16TOH)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(htobe32 "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOBE32)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(htole32 "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOLE32)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(be32toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_BE32TOH)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(le32toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_LE32TOH)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(htobe64 "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOBE64)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(htole64 "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOLE64)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(be64toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_BE64TOH)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(le64toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_LE64TOH)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(htobe16 "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOBE16)
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(bswap_16 "byteswap.h" HAVE_DECL_HTOBE16)
target_compile_definitions(myapp PRIVATE HAVE_ENDIAN_H HAVE_DECL_BSWAP_16 HAVE_DECL_HTOLE16 HAVE_DECL_BE16TOH HAVE_DECL_LE16TOH HAVE_DECL_HTOBE32 HAVE_DECL_HTOLE32 HAVE_DECL_BE32TOH HAVE_DECL_LE32TOH HAVE_DECL_HTOBE64 HAVE_DECL_HTOLE64 HAVE_DECL_BE64TOH HAVE_DECL_LE64TOH HAVE_DECL_HTOBE16)
```

Comment: On Stack Overflow we tend to **not mix** *problems* and *resolutions* in one question post. Everything below "Update 1" you may move into **your own answer** (that is, *self-answering*). Moreover, your solution could create some discussion... As far as I understand, your `target_compile_definitions()` call **unconditionally** defines given macros (that is, result of `CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS()` isn't used). For conditional definition, you could use `target_compile_definition(myapp PRIVATE HAVE_ENDIAN_H=${HAVE_ENDIAN_H} ...)`.

Comment: Oops. I will change the target_compile_definition and test it. After I confirm it, I will post the findings as my own answer. Thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In CMake you can check whether symbol is declared with [CheckSymbolExists](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CheckSymbolExists.html) module. Example:

```
include(CheckSymbolExists)
# ...
# Set HAVE_DECL_LE16TOH variable to 1 or 0 depending on declaration 'le16toh' symbol in 'endian.h' header.
CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS(le16toh "endian.h" HAVE_DECL_LE16TOH)
```

Comparing to `AC_CHECK_DECLS` macro in autotools:

- Call to `CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS()` checks single symbol at once. For check several symbols you may call it in a loop.
- For `CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS()` you need to specify *concrete* list of headers.

  If including of header file depends on some other macro, you need to check this macro first, either with another call to `CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS()` (whether macro is **defined**), or with plain command [try_compile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/try_compile.html) (check **value** of the macro). Alternatively, you may check whether specific header exists with [CheckIncludeFile](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CheckIncludeFile.html) module.
- Additional actions depending on result of `CHECK_SYMBOL_EXISTS()` can be issued after the call with common `if(<var>)` or `if(NOT <var>)`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try it.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. I used "CHECK_INCLUDE_FILE" for HAVE_ENDIAN_H. I think this is fine.